# Can a julia struct be defined with persistent requirements on field dimensions?

Tags: julia

If I define a new struct as

```
mutable struct myStruct
   data::AbstractMatrix
   labels::Vector{String}
end
```

and I want to throw an error if the length of `labels` is not equal to the number of columns of `data`, I know that I can write a constructor that enforces this condition like

```
myStruct(data, labels) = length(labels) != size(data)[2] ? error("Labels incorrect length") : new(data,labels)
```

However, once the struct is initialized, the `labels` field can be set to the incorrect length:

```
m = myStruct(randn(2,2), ["a", "b"])
m.labels = ["a"]
```

Is there a way to throw an error if the `labels` field is ever set to length not equal to the number of columns in `data`?

Comment: If the number of columns is not too great, you can use tuples and possibly StaticArrays.jl.

Comment: Agree with DNF, in general Julia doesn't have "private" or "locked" fields so what to do about it is a bit usecase dependent. E.g. DataFrames hides the column names in a `DataFrames.Index` struct and making everything immutable, although ultimately the user could still mess with this by e.g. `push!`ing a label onto the array that holds the names. They also offer a `rename!` function though to steer the users towards a safe way of renaming (which then errors if users provide a wrong number of labels)

Comment: @DNF what about `SizedArray`? It only wraps another array with the size, it doesn't have to be a bits type like `StaticArrays` nor are they constrained with the arrays needing to be small, as I understood, ie: `mem = OffsetVector(SizedVector{0x10000 |> Int}(zeros(UInt8, 0x10000)), 0x0:0xffff)`  Is this bad usage for example?

Comment: I haven't used `SizedArray`, but it's also part of StaticArrays.jl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `StaticArrays.jl` to fix the matrix and vector's sizes to begin with:

```
using StaticArrays

mutable struct MatVec{R, C, RC, VT, MT}
   data::MMatrix{R, C, MT, RC}  # RC should be R*C
   labels::MVector{C, VT}
end
```

but there's the downside of having to compile for every concrete type with a unique permutation of type parameters `R,C,MT,VT`. `StaticArrays` also does not scale as well as normal `Array`s.

If you don't restrict dimensions in the type parameters (with all those downsides) and want to throw an error at runtime, you got good and bad news.

The good news is you can control whatever mutation happens to your type. `m.labels = v` would call the method `setproperty!(object::myStruct, name::Symbol, v)`, which you can define with all the safeguards you like.

The bad news is that you can't control mutation to the fields' types. `push!(m.labels, 1)` mutates in the `push!(a::Vector{T}, item)` method. The `myStruct` instance itself doesn't actually change; it still points to the same `Vector`. If you can't guarantee that you won't do something like `x = m.labels; push!(x, "whoops")` , then you really do need runtime checks, like `iscorrect(m::myStruct) = length(m.labels) == size(m.data)[2]`

Comment: What about `StaticArrays.SizedArray`? Please see my comment above.

Comment: @HarmonicaMuse Yes that is also an option. I don't know how the performance scales for that, the docs do mention that `SizedArray`s use some static array methods. However it's worth noting that this would still require compilation for every `R,C,MT,VT`.

Comment: Occurred to me you can at least dodge the `push!` issue without baking dimensions into myStruct's type parameters: make sure `labels` is a `SubArray` (`view` constructor). You can still `push!` to `my_struct.labels.parent`, but at least that won't be visible to `my_struct.labels`. However, `insert!` on the parent array will also shift elements in the view. Really, any approach backed by a 1D array is not nearly as immune as `StaticArrays` or using a 2D (1xC) matrix instead.

Answer (score 2):

A good option is to not access the fields of your struct directly. Instead, do it using a function. Eg:

```
mutable struct MyStruct
   data::AbstractMatrix
   labels::Vector{String}
end

function modify_labels(s::MyStruct, new_labels::Vector{String})
    # do all checks and modifications
end
```

You should check chapter 8 from "Hands-On Design Patterns and Best Practices with Julia: Proven solutions to common problems in software design for Julia 1.x"